# Quite strange MinGW ld problem - "collect2: ld returned 1 exit status"

Tags: c++, windows-xp, mingw32, openframeworks

I'm building an application for data visualization and the framework I'm using is beautiful [OpenFrameworks](http://openframeworks.cc/). On Linux, it compiles and works perfectly, but now it's time to port it to Windows and I'm facing some very strange problems. I can't find relevant information from google. When linking, I get this:

```
mingw32-g++.exe  -o bin\visualisation.exe ...blah.o, blah2.o... ...lib1 lib2 lib3...
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
Process terminated with status 1 (0 minutes, 3 seconds)
0 errors, 0 warnings
```

(list of object files an libraries is quite long, so I stripped it a bit)

I tried manually building all libraries from scratch and then trying again, but I always get this. No errors, it just doesn't create any executables. It is usually problem with not included library, but then linker gives an error. I also tried to build all from command line, and I get the same result.

So, my question is pretty obvious, where can be the problem?

Just to mention, I'm using Code::Blocks 8.02, Windows XP Home SP3 and MinGW with following components:

```
gcc-core-3.4.5-20060117-1-vista.tar.gz 
gcc-g++-3.4.5-20060117-1-vista.tar.gz 
mingw-runtime-3.14.tar.gz 
mingw32-make-3.81-2.tar.gz
mingw-utils-0.3.tar.gz
w32api-3.11.tar.gz
binutils-2.18.50-20080109.tar.gz
gdb-6.7.50.20071127-mingw.tar.bz2
```

Edit:
Log when compiling from command line (cmd.exe):

```
C:\openFrameworks\apps\examples\GraphVisualOFv2>mingw32-g++.exe  -o     bin\visualisation.exe obj\release\src\dataAccess\DBDataLoader.o obj\release\src\dataAccess\DataLoader.o obj\release\src\dataAccess\XMLDataLoader.o obj\release\src\dataAccess\c\sacapidll.o obj\release\src\engine\Engine.o obj\release\src\engine\config\Configuration.o obj\release\src\engine\config\ConfigurationControler.o obj\release\src\graph\Edge.o obj\release\src\graph\Graph.o obj\release\src\graph\Vertex.o obj\release\src\main.o obj\release\src\math\AlgorithmicPositioning.o obj\release\src\math\Positioning.o obj\release\src\math\RandomPositioning.o obj\release\src\metaLayer\MetaEdge.o obj\release\src\metaLayer\MetaGraph.o obj\release\src\metaLayer\MetaVertex.o obj\release\src\testApp.o   ../../../libs/openFrameworksCompiled/lib/win_cb/openFrameworks.lib ../../../libs/FreeImage/lib/win_cb/FreeImage.lib ../../../libs/rtAudio/lib/win_cb/librtaudio.a ../../../libs/rtAudio/lib/win_cb/RtAudio.a ../../../libs/rtAudio/lib/win_cb/RtAudioD.a ../../../libs/quicktime/lib/win_cb/qtmlClient.lib ../../../libs/freetype/lib/win_cb/libfreetype.a ../../../libs/glut/lib/win_cb/libglut.a ../../../libs/videoInput/lib/win_cb/videoInputLib.a ../../../libs/fmodex/lib/win_cb/libfmodex.a ../../../libs/glee/lib/win_cb/GLee.lib ../../../libs/glew/lib/win_cb/glew32s.lib ../../../libs/glu/lib/win_cb/glu32.lib ../../../libs/poco/lib/win_cb/libPocoNetmt.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/win_cb/libPocoUtilmt.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/win_cb/libPocoXMLmt.a ../../../libs/poco/lib/win_cb/libPocoFoundationmt.a ../../../libs/asa/lib/win_cb/dbcapi.lib ../../../libs/asa/lib/win_cb/dbextenv11.lib ../../../libs/asa/lib/win_cb/dblibtm.lib ../../../libs/asa/lib/win_cb/dbmlsynccli11.lib ../../../libs/asa/lib/win_cb/dbtlstm.lib ../../../libs/asa/lib/win_cb/odbc32.lib ../../../libs/asa/lib/win_cb/qany11.lib ../../../libs/dlfcn/lib/libdl.a ../../../libs/rudeconfig/lib/librudeconfig.a ../../../libs/freeglut/lib/libfreeglut.a -lopengl32 -lglu32 -ldsound -lwinmm -ldxguid -lstrmbase -lstrmiids -lz -luuid -lole32 -loleaut32 -lsetupapi -lwsock32 -lws2_32 -lIphlpapi
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

C:\openFrameworks\apps\examples\GraphVisualOFv2>
```

Comment: Well, "ld returned 1 exit status" means linking failed. The error text, which you did not post, explains what the problem is.

Comment: How are you linking your program.  You are getting linking errors so something has gone wrong there.  Are you using a makefile, or a development suite.You might want to try one of the cross platform builders such as cmake or bjam, if you are not using one of these already.

Comment: @Erik: exactly! @Leon: Without the actual line, we can't help you at all.

Comment: As I said, there is no errors, and that is why I said it is a strange problem. I'm aware that linking failed, but don't know why, since ld is not giving me any information. I tried rebuilding everything numerous times with various compiler flags, but I always get the same result...

Comment: @Tom: I'm linking with Code::Blocks integrated configuration. Makefile is pretty obfuscated and works on Linux, but in Windows is unusable in my case.

Comment: what happens when you run that command directly in `cmd.exe`?

Comment: @Mat: I get identical result. I'll post log in question body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution by setting up an environment to directly call ld.exe with

> -verbose

flag and got tons of information. I actually forgot to setup opengl32 development libraries, so linker could not find them.

Comment: And that's exactly a reason why you should use an up to date toolchain. MinGW GCC has progressed to version 4.5.2 in the last 5 years. Version 3.4.5 is stone-age old, and the binutils (which `ld` is part of) is two years younger, which could explain the inability of gcc to flush the error through.